# graded ring associated to a line bundle in a tensor category

Tags: line-bundles, ag.algebraic-geometry, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian tensor category with unit $\mathcal{O}$. An object $\mathcal{L}$ is called invertible or a line bundle if there is some $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ such that $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{-1} \cong \mathcal{L}^{-1} \otimes \mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{O}$. Equivalently, $\mathcal{L} \otimes -$ is an equivalence of categories. Now define a graded ring $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{L})$ as follows:

As an abelian group, take the direct sum of the $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$, where $n \geq 0$. The product of homogenuous elements $s : \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}, t : \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m}$ is defined by $s \otimes t$, where we identify $\mathcal{O} \otimes \mathcal{O} \cong \mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m} \cong \mathcal{L}^{\otimes (n+m)}$.

**Question** Is $\Gamma_\*(\mathcal{L})$ commutative? Note that this is known in degree $0$ since $\text{End}(\mathcal{O})$ is commutative, even if we do not assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is symmetric. Actually it's not hard to see that $\text{End}(\mathcal{O})$ is central in $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{L})$. Remark that all this is well-known in the case of $\mathcal{A} = \text{Qcoh}(X)$ for a scheme $X$.

Comment: I've been told that the answer is no in the more general case of just a monoidal category (without additive structure): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34981/from-tensor-algebras-in-monoidal-categories-to-commutative-monoids

 I am very much interested in this question, however, and maybe just getting a non-commutative graded ring with nice properties could allow one to do non-commutative projective geometry in the Artin-Zhang sense.

Comment: What about graded modules over a graded-commutative ring, where the tensor structure switches signs?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Chris: There is no doubt that $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{L})$ is a (noncomm.) graded $\text{End}(\mathcal{O})$-algebra. I don't understand the answers in your question (perhaps my one is a duplicate?). So the claim is true if $\mathcal{A}$ is symmetric? How do we prove that? What are counterexamples in the general case? @Tyler: What do you mean by "switches signs"?

Comment: @Martin: Let $R$ be a graded exterior algebra on x and y, with |x| = |y| = 1, and consider the category of graded left $R$-modules.  The tensor structure is given by `$M \otimes_R N$`, where any left $R$-module $M$ inherits a right action by $m \cdot r = (-1)^{|m| |r|} rm$.  (This is the sign switch I referred to.)  If $\mathcal{L} = R[1]$ (a shifted copy of $R$), then the graded ring `$\Gamma_*(\mathcal{L})$` is isomorphic as a graded ring to $R$ and is noncommutative.

Comment: (And this category is symmetric monoidal.)

Comment: @Tyler: your comment, I think, answers the question in the negative.  You should leave it as an answer.  Be careful (or rather, be more explicit) about whether you mean $R[1]$ or $R[-1]$.  What you want are that $\operatorname{Hom}(R,R[1]) = \operatorname{span}(x,y)$.  If you shift the other direction, then there are no maps, and `$\Gamma_*(L)$` is just the $R$-linear (degree-$0$) endomorphisms of $R$, i.e. just the ground field.

Comment: The reason Tyler's example works is that Martin is taking the "wrong" notion of "commutative".  Tyler's category has a particular choice for the braiding $L\otimes L \to L\otimes L$, and it is not the identity map.  But in Martin's definition, he wants the commutativity with respect to the "identity braiding" $R[1] \otimes R[1] \cong R[1+1] \cong R[1+1] \cong R[1] \otimes R[1]$, given by the "braiding" that switches the two $1$s in $2 = 1+1$.  Note that lots of writers working with supergeometry aren't careful about this type of thing, and so have sign errors in their published papers.

Comment: It would be great if someone gives an answer which is also comprehensive for readers who have just started to learn something about tensor categories ;). I have no idea what all these bradings and symmetries are about, if and to what extent they are important here and if there is a nice criterion for $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{L})$ to be commutative, perhaps adding extra structure on the tensor category.

Comment: @Martin: I am not able to give a comprehensive answer at the moment, but would like to think more about this. Perhaps you can clarify the context in which you want an answer. At least part of why the answer is yes in $QCoh(X)$ uses the symmetric monoidal structure (for every pair $E,F$ there is a specified and functorial isomorphism $E \otimes F \simeq F \otimes E$ satisfying various compatibilities and such that composing with $F \otimes E \simeq E \otimes F$ in either direction gives the identity.) Are you happy to use a symmetric monoidal structure? What kind of commutativity do you want?

Comment: @Martin: a comment on your first comment to my first comment. The `maybe' was not about whether you get an algebra but about whether just having an algebra (possibly non-commutative) might suffice for various applications. Also, I don't think your question is quite a duplicate and is generating more conversation. In particular, Tyler's example is revealing. 

Answer (score 3):

The following arose originally as a comment above and is being moved to an answer (per suggestion).

Let $R = R^*$ be any graded ring which is graded-commutative in the sense of homological algebra, i.e. for homogeneous elements $x$ and $y$ we have $xy = (-1)^{|x| |y|} yx$.  Consider the category of graded left $R$-modules.  This has a tensor structure as follows.  Any left $R$-module $M$ inherits a right action by $R$ via the formula $m\cdot r=(−1)^{∣m∣∣r∣}rm$.  Using this, we can define a monoidal structure on left $R$-modules using the graded tensor product $M \otimes_R N$.

(Note that all of this really comes because graded abelian groups form a symmetric monoidal category under tensor product, using twist isomorphism $\tau(x \otimes y) = (-1)^{|x| |y|} y \otimes x$.  In this category, $R$ is a commutative monoid object and the tensor is just defined by a standard coequalizer on modules.)

Now let $\mathcal{L} = R[1]$, by which I mean a shifted copy of $R$ so that the degree $n$ group $R[1]^n$ is $R^{n+1}$ (grading cohomologically in order to align with the delicate sensibilities of the ag.algebraic-geometry tag).  As a left $R$-module, it is free on a generator $e$ with $|e|=-1$.  Then this object is invertible, and tensor powers $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n} = R[n]$ are free on generators $e^{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

At this point, one should verify for themselves that the ring $\Gamma_*(\mathcal L)$ is isomorphic to $R$ as a graded ring.  (Seriously, you should check this, especially if you usually take the attitude that "the signs just work themselves out".  There may be a clever perspective that avoids sign issues, but the straightforward perspective is not so.)

However, if you choose not to verify this:

One then gets an identification $Hom_{gr. R-mod}(R, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}) \cong R[n]^{0} = R^n \cdot e_n$, and the multiplicative structure is given by $$r e^{|r|} \cdot s e^{|s|} = (-1)^{|r| |s|} (rs) e^{|rs|}.$$  In particular, this graded ring is noncommutative precisely when $R$ is noncommutative, (which is most of the time).

ADDED: You can verify that there is an isomporphism between $R$ and this ring, given by the formula:
$$
\phi(r) = (-1)^{\binom{|r|}{2}} r \cdot e^r
$$
There is *no* canonical sign switch if you use $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded objects rather than $\mathbb{Z}$-graded objects (although mod-4 gradings are fine).